# Combining two SQL statements with subtraction

Tags: sql, vba

I have two sql statements that I am looking to combine. I am sure that this can be done using a join command of some sort but I am not very good at using them so I was hoping someone could help from here.

I want to start with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2.EVLEV1 AS WOSFROM 
FROM 
  CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2, 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('0',CPJDDTA81.F4801.WADOCO) AS WOS 
    FROM 
      CPJDDTA81.F4801,
      CPJDDTA81.F4102 
    WHERE 
          CPJDDTA81.F4102 .IBITM = CPJDDTA81.F4801.WAITM 
      AND CPJDDTA81.F4801.WASRST IN( '30', '45' ) 
      AND CPJDDTA81.F4102.IBSRP4 IN( 'ECT' )
      AND CPJDDTA81.F4801.WAMMCU = '      ECT001'
  ) SELECTEDWOS 
WHERE 
      CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2.EVLEV1 = WOS 
  AND CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2.EVLAB1 = 'E500'
```

and to subtract from that list anything that is in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2.EVLEV1 AS WOSTOSUBTRACT 
FROM 
  CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2, 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('0',CPJDDTA81.F4801.WADOCO) AS WOS 
    FROM 
      CPJDDTA81.F4801, 
      CPJDDTA81.F4102 
    WHERE 
          CPJDDTA81.F4102.IBITM = CPJDDTA81.F4801.WAITM 
      AND CPJDDTA81.F4801.WASRST IN( '30', '45' ) 
      AND CPJDDTA81.F4102.IBSRP4 IN( 'CAB' )
      AND CPJDDTA81.F4801.WAMMCU = '      STH001'
  ) SELECTEDWOS 
WHERE 
  CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2.EVLEV1 = WOS
```

I am doing it in adodb vba which sometimes limits the types of sql commands used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In combination with what you guys helped with and changing things around I have a solution for anyone who cares:

```
SELECT WOSTO, AREATO, WOSFROM, STATIONFROM
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('0', WADOCO) AS WOSTO, IBSRP4 AS AREATO
      , WOSFROM AS WOSFROM, PWOSFROM AS PWOSFROM, STATIONFROM AS STATIONFROM
   FROM CPJDDTA81.F4801
      , CPJDDTA81.F4102
      ,
      (
         SELECT DISTINCT EVLEV1 AS WOSFROM, EVLAB2 AS PWOSFROM
            , EVLAB1 AS STATIONFROM
         FROM CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2
            ,
            (
               SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('0', WADOCO) AS WOS
               FROM CPJDDTA81.F4801, CPJDDTA81.F4102
               WHERE IBITM = WAITM
                  AND WASRST IN( '30', '45' )
                  AND IBSRP4 IN( 'ECT' )
                  AND WAMMCU = '      ECT001'
            ) AS SELECTEDWOS
            WHERE EVLEV1 = WOS
               AND EVLAB1 = 'E500'
      ) AS ORIGINALWOS
      WHERE IBITM = WAITM
         AND WAPARS = PWOSFROM
         AND IBSRP4 = 'CAB'
         AND WAMMCU = '      STH001'
) AS SELECTEDWOS
LEFT JOIN CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2 ON SELECTEDWOS.WOSTO = CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2.EVLEV1
WHERE CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2.EVLEV1 IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried to format your query, but I am not sure it is 100% correct.  Please correct me if I made an error.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could handle this would be with [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

If this is not an option, you could also try using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EVLEV1 AS WOSFROM 
FROM CLOCFILEOT.CKEVNHM2
   , 
   (
      SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('0', WADOCO) AS WOS 
      FROM CPJDDTA81.F4801
         , CPJDDTA81.F4102 
      WHERE IBITM = WAITM 
         AND WASRST IN( '30', '45' ) 
         AND IBSRP4 IN( 'ECT' )
         AND WAMMCU = '      ECT001'
   ) AS SELECTEDWOS 
WHERE EVLEV1 = WOS 
   AND EVLAB1 = 'E500'
   AND EVLEV1 NOT IN
   (
      SubQuery Here
   )
```

Comment: You can left join and look for null

Answer (score 0):

In the first query... I'm not sure why you're doing a cross join and geting distinct from one of the tables.  You can eliminate the second table altogether.  If you'd like better answers.. you'll have to let us know which table the columns are coming from.

You can either left join and look for nulls

```
select <col a>
from <table A> 
left join <table B>
  on <col a> = <col b>
where <col b> is not null
```

or do ..

```
select <col a>
from <table A>
where <col a> not in (
    select <col b>
    from <table B>)
```

Comment: My guess is the first WHERE clause IBITM = WAITM is actually joining the two tables together.

Comment: got it... I think it would really be helpful if we knew which tables the columns belong to.

Comment: I have updated my sql statement above to reflect the table names with the columns.